# cloudbees deployer DeployException: Cannot find user null after successful build

Tags: java, playframework, cloudbees, playframework-2.2

It's something strange and looks like a bug to me.

A week ago I've created a Play! Framework 2 app with cloudbees ClickStart. Everything was working fine, was rebuilding from GitHub fine, was deploying fine.

The crucial thing is that in the build configuration of this one week old app post-build part looks like this:
[image]

The app I've created today with cloudbees ClickStart has different post-build part:
[image]

For some reason (Jenkins) has disappeared from Credentials and Account drop-down is empty.

It builds app successfully but then shows an error:

```
com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.exceptions.DeployException: Cannot find user null
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunEngineImpl.<init>(RunEngineImpl.java:75)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunEngineImpl$FactoryImpl.build(RunEngineImpl.java:170)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunEngineImpl$FactoryImpl.build(RunEngineImpl.java:161)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:103)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:790)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:762)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:715)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1617)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
```

Is it a bug or a feature???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is caused when you disable one of the CloudBees DEV@cloud plugins. Try to re-enable or re-install the CloudBees Credentials Plugin.

### Update (2014-01-08)

A newer root cause is applicable if your Jenkins instance was hibernated or restarted any time after mid-November 2013. For these cases:

The update of DEV@cloud to the `cloudbees-folder` plugin version 4.0 (which only kicks in when your Jenkins instance is restarted after Nov 13th 2013) requires that the `credentials` plugin be upgraded to the latest (at least 1.9.3) and the `ssh-credentials` and `ssh-slaves` plugins be upgraded to the latest versions and Jenkins restarted.

Comment: Works! Thx! Where did you get the answer? Some documentation?

Comment: Steven has yet to decloak his StackOverflow account... and he got the info from me...

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same problem. After deleting a post-build action (i.e. **Publish JUnit test results report**) from the project's configuration the **Jenkins** option disappeared from the **Credentials** drop down. I updated [Credentials Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) from 1.7.6 to 1.9.4, restarted Jenkins, and it works again!